# cannot load such file - sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, load

I apologize if this question is not useful but i haven't find solutions for this problem here or in the internet.

I am running my rails server on Windows 10 (64-bit). I have rails version 4.2.1 and ruby version 2.2.4.

I already followed many tutorial to fx this but it not worked. I tried uninstall sqlite3 and reinstall it again. I downloaded new dll files and replace it in ruby22-x64/bin.

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
    from C:/Projekty/Atelier/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It looks like windows machine, so I am gona say it is just beginning of your problems. You will save yourself a lot of tears by switching to unix system, ruby does not play very well with Windows at the moment.

Comment: Ok thank you. So i will switch to unix.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, with Ruby 2.2.2

`bundle install sqlite3`

Will fix this.

Comment: This gives an error: bundle install needs to be called as `bundle install [OPTIONS]`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

`bundle update sqlite3` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing natively with the official compiler directive:

```
gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-include=dir --with-sqlite3-lib=dir
```

http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Try, on your project terminal:

> bundle update sqlite3
>
> bundle update nokogiri

That worked for me
I hope i have helped you ;)